# Options for select list from model variables and for loop

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have a model containing users, I want to make a dropdown list with these users' UserName as display and their IDs as values, but it is not working. Whichever user I choose from the dropdown list, when I proceed, the chosen value seems to be the Id of the current user, no matter which I choose.

When replacing this select with an input box the other part which uses the user Id works just fine. It seems as all value attributes for the options become the current user's Id instead of the chosen ones.

I've tried injecting javascript, I've tried changing the value=Item.Id for other things, nothing so far has worked. The dropdown list does become populated, but the value attribute seems to be off somehow.

```
        <select asp-for="Input.UserID" onfocus="this.select()">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
            {
            <option value=Item.Id>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</option>
            }
        </select>
```

The webpage always throws an error stating that the chosen User ID is the one of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the `value=""` attribute of the `<option>` element correctly. You also don't need to use `DisplayFor` for a string value.

```
<select asp-for="Input.UserID">
@foreach( var item in this.Model.Users ) {
    <option value="@(item.Id)">@(item.UserName)</option>
}
</select>
```

That said, consider using this instead:

```
<select asp-for="Input.UserID" asp-items="@this.Model.UsersOptions"></select>
```

You'll need to add a `List<SelectListItem> UsersOptions` to your ViewModel for this to work.